# How to have an unordered list with a Font Awesome icon and list text to have the same hover state in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm learning Bootstrap and have several questions that I cannot seem to find answers to. I will ask one question at a time though.  My first question:

I am trying to create an unordered list with icons and some text next to each other. I would like for both the text AND the icon to change their hover state ***at the same time***. However, I seem to only be able to get the icon ***OR*** the text to highlight ***OR*** I can get both to highlight but not at the same time. Ideally, I would like it if a user hovered over the text that the icon would also change it's hover state and vice versa. Can someone take a look at the code here on JSFiddle and tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

http://jsfiddle.net/k1o45e5g/

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-list" alt="Dry Cleaning Services"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right right-circle-icon"></i>Dry Cleaning</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-list" alt="Dry Cleaning Services"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right right-circle-icon"></i>Shirt Laundry</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-list" alt="Dry Cleaning Services"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right right-circle-icon"></i>Wet Clothing</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-list" alt="Dry Cleaning Services"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right right-circle-icon"></i>In-house Alterations</a></li></ul>
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

PS: I hope I inserted the code properly as requested. This is my first post so if I inserted it incorrectly please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do about bootstrap. Its about css priority rules. You gave color to icon by class

```
.right-circle-icon {
    font-size: 18pt;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 15px;
    color: #808080; <--
}
```

Then on hover of its parent element you set another color

```
.btn-list:hover {
    color: #963050;
}
```

The first rule is stronger for icon element, so its gets color from that (even when hover on anchor parent element). If you remove color from .right-circle-icon, hover on any anchor element should give hover color to icon too.

If you do not want to remove color from .right-circle-icon then you should add

```
.btn-list:hover .right-circle-icon{
        color: #963050;
    }
```

You will not need in any case

```
.right-circle-icon:hover {
    color: #963050;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that about icon elements.